Code signing provider that works with Linux binary (executable) files
A bit of a background:
In the recent security changes, code signing private key is stored in HSM (local or remote).  Most of the providers like DigiCert, Globalsign provide ways to sign files using their tools.  DigiCert provides the smctl to communicate with its KeyLocker and uses third party tools like JarSigner, jSign, osslsigncode to do the signing.  Getting osslsigncode to work on some Linux system has shown a lot of pain and DigiCert is giving up on it. Globalsign uses JarSigner for signing jars in Linux.
The problem:
The tools can sign files with specific and limited list of extensions.  They cannot sign Linux executables (scripts or binary) because of unsupported "extensions".
The question:
Do you know a provider that can sign Linux executables?
Forgive me if this is an inappropriate question.
